# Why do async/await ignored with hub.On in latest SignalR client and works sequentially?

Tags: c#, .net, async-await, signalr.client, .net-core-3.1

I have a .NetCore 3.1 Windows Service (client) that's communicating with a SignalR Hub (server).
Server sends a bunch of messages, which should start a long-term tasks concurrently, not blocking the main thread.
To achieve this I use async/await on registering handler:

```
var subscription = _connection
                .On<Launch>(
                    Methods.Launch,
                    async (payload) => await Handler(payload)
                    );
```

My handler looks like:

```
    private async Task<bool> Handler(Payload payload)
    {
        _logger.LogInformation($"Launch STARTED | Id: {payload.Id}");
        await Task.Delay(3000);
        _logger.LogInformation($"Launch DONE | Id: {payload.Id}");
        return true;
    }
```

Having async/await in action I'm waiting in console for something like

```
Launch STARTED | Id: 1
Launch STARTED | Id: 2
Launch STARTED | Id: 3
Launch STARTED | Id: 4
Launch DONE | Id: 1
Launch DONE | Id: 3
Launch DONE | Id: 2
Launch DONE | Id: 4
```

but getting:

```
Launch STARTED | Id: 1
Launch DONE | Id: 1
Launch STARTED | Id: 2
Launch DONE | Id: 2
Launch STARTED | Id: 3
Launch DONE | Id: 3
Launch STARTED | Id: 4
Launch DONE | Id: 4
```

The interesting thing is that `Microsoft.AspNetCore.SignalR.Client ver1.1.0` works as I need. Such behavior appeared after upgrade to the latest `Microsoft.AspNetCore.SignalR.Client ver3.1.4`.

Is there a way to achieve "concurrent/non blocking" handling of incoming messages in latest SignalR.Client?

Comment: Sounds like a semantic change in `Microsoft.AspNetCore.SignalR.Client`; I'd recommend [asking the team that developed that](https://github.com/dotnet/aspnetcore).

Answer (score 0):

Indeed,this is the expected behavior of message dispatching mechanism. 
Explanation is related to:

[#2084](https://github.com/aspnet/SignalR/issues/2084),
[#2086](https://github.com/aspnet/SignalR/issues/2086) and then [#5351](https://github.com/dotnet/aspnetcore/issues/5351)

as a workaround I've changed my code the next way:

```
var subscription = _connection
            .On<Launch>(
                Methods.Launch,
                payload => { _ = Handler(payload); } // <= here is fire-and-forget stuff
                );
```

And now it works the way I need.